# how can create mvc entity framework apart price list scheduling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, date, fullcalendar

I have a new project for apart retail with mvc, c# and entityframework. I am using fullcalendar in my project. Now my problem is;

First i am creating a new event all days. No problem. But some days contain different events. I want to just change time interval for special dates. I have create Fullcalendar Model.

```
public class FullCalendar
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public long start { get; set; }
        public long end { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }


    }
```

for example general date event in my database Rates table ;

```
id  RateForDate    RateForWeek    RateForMonth    StartDate     EndDate   IsAllDay
1   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-04-30    2020-12-31  True
```

and special dates in Rates table;

```
id  RateForDate       RateForWeek   RateForMonth  StartDate     EndDate   IsAllDay
2   100,00            90,00     80,00         2013-05-05    2013-05-05  False
3   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-05-06    2013-05-10  False
4   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-06-05    2013-06-10  False
5   230,00            200,00    180,00        2013-07-12    2013-07-15  False
```

but in general date events **dont must be change other days**  when  special days interpose in include general date events. Just change special days . And other days must be general date events.

new Rates table must be like;

```
id  RateForDate       RateForWeek   RateForMonth  StartDate     EndDate   IsAllDay
1   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-04-30    2013-05-04  False
2   100,00            90,00     80,00         2013-05-05    2013-05-05  False
3   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-05-06    2013-06-04  False
4   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-06-05    2013-06-10  False
5   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-06-11    2013-07-11  False
6   230,00            200,00    180,00        2013-07-12    2013-07-15  False
7   180,00            150,00    100,00        2013-07-16    2020-05-05  False
```

I hope I can tell my problem. How can i create algorithim for this problem? ho can create foreach for this problem? thanks for helps. And i am sorry for english.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the rates for a period of, say, 30 days, you could do:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(y,m,d);
var rates = new List<FullCalendar>();
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    var date = startDate.AddDays(i);
    rates.Add(GetSpecialRate(date) ?? GetStandardRate(date));
}
```

where `GetSpecialRate` and `GetStandardRate` are two methods by which you get a rate. The main part in both of these methods is

```
rates.Where(r => r.StartDate >= date && r.EndDate < date)
```

`rates` is either the collection of standard rates or the special rates.

Side note: do not use `long` for `DateTime`, it's a debugging hell. Convert `DateTime` to `long` when it's necessary e.g. for Json serialization.